# How to exclude products from cart price rules? Seems to not work

Tags: magento2

I tried every combination in both the conditions and action options but I am not getting what I want. Does anybody know how to exclude one or more products from getting a volume discount?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can change condition from :

SKU **does not contain** DR-TAPE1 **to** SKU **is not** DR-TAPE1

When you change form `does not contain` to `is not`, it will open product selector and you can choose from available SKUs

**NOTE:** **is not** will only work for single SKU. If you need to put multiple SKUs, You need to use **is not one of**.

**is not one of** will check form number of sku

Hope above will help!

Comment: Thanks, tried that already but it does not work

https://ibb.co/bRV3BjD

Comment: @SandervanZuidam, I have tried both `is not ` and `is not one of`, both is working fine.

Comment: @SandervanZuidam, did you cleared cache and checking correct SKU product ?

Comment: Are you using multiple SKU's in your cart? Did you apply it to conditions or actions? Yes I have cleared cache and I have 2 products in my cart. 1 of them is the sku that has the is not in the rule. It's still counted when giving discount on volume

Comment: Yes multiple SKU in rule, i added in action, i added 2 product 1 is qualify for rule and other is not. cart showing discount only for qualify item.

Comment: @SandervanZuidam, did it worked ?

Comment: No nothing works with excluding :-(

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable SKU attribute for using in promos? To check it, go to Stores ->> Product ->> SKU ->> Storefront properties ->> Use for Promo Rule Conditions. "Use for Promo Rule Conditions" has to be set to "Yes"..